# Angular CLI / Run two categories of test with ng test

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have two different types of tests:

- Unit tests (standard angular cli **.spec.ts** files)
- Functional tests (my specific **.func.spec.ts** files, works the same way as .spec.ts files, but not mocked and injects data in my db, so no need to run them all the time)

I am trying to :

- Exclude the .func.spec.ts files from the `ng test` command to only run **.spec.ts** test file
- Call the test command to only run **.func.spec.ts**

So my functional tests are not executed in the regular `ng test` context and can be run separately.

In other words the solution can be...

- `npm run test` runs .spec.ts files
- `npm run test:func` runs .func.spec.ts files

I tried to create a different karma config file that excludes the files I don't want but it does not work.

Do you have any idea of how to perform this?

Comment: you can edit it in the package.json file

Comment: @Azalkor problem is not the command, problem is the file exclusion for the two kind of test execution

Comment: you should be able to edit a "test:func" command running karma *.func.spec.ts don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add a specific Karama configuration karma.func.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    files: ['src/app/**/**.func.ts'] // Not 100% sure about the pattern
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev' //you could change to use prod
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Add to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "test:func": "ng test --config karma.func.conf.js"
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

Maybe there is another solution that will avoid maintaining two configuration files.

Comment: This does not work because of the Angular CLI specificities with Karma.
Every tests are still runned when adding
`files: [
      '**/*.func.spec.ts',`

Comment: You are right the problem is that currently angular cli karma plugin will add spec.ts in test.ts. So you need to change it but i'm not sure how you can change it dynamically.